# Xamarin Forms ListView in TableView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, tableview

I am trying to build a page that has a few sections, two of which contain short lists that would benefit from [ListView context actions](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Context_Actions). Using a TableView that contains ListViews seems like a great fit. However, it doesn't seem to work.

The fact that both TableView and ListView implement scrolling may contribute to the problem. In this use case, I don't want the ListViews to scroll. Is there a way to nest a ListView in a TableView? Is there any other approach to presenting this kind of UI?

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling is certainly an issue with this approach and the two controls won't mix well together.

Using a Grouped ListView is most likely the best approach, if you want sections with headings.

You will need to group your data first. Below is an example.

```
public class PersonList : List<Person>
{
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons => this;
}
```

Then in your ListView you need to enable grouping via IsGroupingEnabled, then provide a GroupHeaderTemplate.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyGroupedData}"
          IsGroupingEnabled="true">
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Heading}" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Example taken from: [Xamarin Forms ListView Grouping](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/)

Comment: Since the appearance of ListView groups differs from TableView sections, if other parts of the app use TableViews, the UI of the page with the ListView hack will be inconsistent. The fundamental problem is that the collections of data in the two sections are fundamentally different, which is the opposite of what the grouping idiom is designed to convey.

Comment: You can change the look and feel of a heading in a ListView to however you choose. In regards to grouping different types of data, you can use a DataTemplateSelector. Otherwise the only other alternative would be to either create a custom StackLayout or Grid, or a custom TableViewCell and manually create the entire functionality around ContextActions.

Comment: Neither of the options seem easy. :-( Trying to mimic the native UI for TableView section headings across all platforms and OS versions sounds like a lot of work. Likewise for re-implementing ContextActions.

Comment: The only other hacky work around I can think of, is creating a custom ListViewRenderer, and disabling/removing the Scrolling.

Comment: @EdwardBrey have a look at the [Evolve app](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve) by James Montemagno it has multiple `ListView` controls on one page but like Adam stated; they do not scroll and it leans towards hacky. But it works, looks great and I've used it a couple of times

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a fixed `ListView.RowHeight` and don't use headers or footers, it turns out that ListView will work inside another ScrollView (such as is included in TableView). The user experience isn't perfect: if the ListView receives a scroll gesture but the outer view doesn't need to scroll, the ListView gives the user false feedback that it can scroll. You can see this in the [Xamarin 
Evolve](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve) app, for example.

ListView works in this situation because it can quickly calculate its height. If the row height is not consistent and known in advance, ListView tells its container that it's as tall as the page, which the outer ScrollView takes at face value.

This limitation often isn't too bad. If you don't have fixed-height rows, the context actions might not always look good anyway, and a different design approach, such as putting commands on a detail page, might be a better choice.

Another gotcah is that you [can't put variable-sized cells](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.TableView.HasUnevenRows/) in a TableView on iOS, unless you're willing to measure the height yourself. An alternative approach to grouping is to use Frames.